# Stacked Bar Chart Y axis Values Missing

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a wide data frame and am using the following code to produce a stacked bar graph; however, the values on the Y axis are missing and I'm not sure why. I assume it has something to do with stacking the columns. You can see I tried to manually set the Y axis within my code but the graph did not capture that command.

**CODE:**

```
g9.bar(ALL_BOARD['Day'], ALL_BOARD["Acute_Count"], label='Acute_Count',color=('blue'),edgecolor='white')
g9.bar(ALL_BOARD['Day'], ALL_BOARD["ICU_Count"],  bottom=ALL_BOARD["Acute_Count"],label='ICU_Count', color=('red'),edgecolor='white')
g9.bar(ALL_BOARD['Day'], ALL_BOARD["PSYCH_Count"], bottom=bars,label='PSYCH_Count', color=('black'),edgecolor='white')
loc = WeekdayLocator(byweekday=MO, interval=1)
g9.xaxis.set_major_locator(loc)
g9.set_ylabel('Boarding Counts')
g9.tick_params(labelrotation=22.5)
g9.set_title('ED Total Boarders by Unit')
y = [0,10,20,30,40,50]
plt.yticks(y)
g9.legend(["Acute_Count","ICU_Count","PSYCH_Count"],
         loc='upper left', frameon=False)
```

**Datatable:**

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE**

When my dataset has this structure and I run this code, the graph has a Y axis that is populated with values. But when I try to select just the variable of interest (second code), I the Y axis values disappear again.

```
ALL_BOARD.plot(ax=g9,x='Day' ,kind='bar', stacked=True, title='Stacked Bar Graph by dataframe')

ALL_BOARD.plot(ax=g9,x='Day', y=['Acute_Count','ICU_Count','PSYCH_Count'],kind='bar', stacked=True,
        title='Stacked Bar Graph by dataframe')
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you replace `g9.tick_params(labelrotation=22.5)` with `g9.tick_params(axis='x', labelrotation=22.5)`? Could you remove `plt.yticks(y)`? (removing this call would show the real y-values)

Comment: @JohanC good idea but that still does not work.

Comment: Telling *"but that still does not work"* without more explanation, doesn't seem to be very helpful. Could you edit the post and add how the plot looks like without the dubious ` plt.yticks(y)`? Could you add some reproducible data as text? Could you add imports etc. to make a standalone example? You might want to reread [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @JohanC sorry, removing the 'plt.yticks(y)' does not impact the population of the values on the y axis - they still do not appear. The graph remains the same as it does in the original post.

Comment: Could you add some reproducible data as text? Could you add imports etc. to make a standalone example? You might want to reread [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Note that your problem is not reproducible with the code shown.

Comment: figured it out - simply added this line of code 'g9.set_yticks(np.arange(0, 60, 10))'

Answer (score 0):

This code provided the desired results:

```
ALL_BOARD_C=ALL_BOARD.drop(['Acute_Hours','ICU_Hours','PSYCH_Hours','index'],axis=1)
ALL_BOARD_C.plot(ax=g9,x='Day' ,kind='bar', stacked=True, title='ED Total Boarders by Unit')
loc = WeekdayLocator(byweekday=MO, interval=1)
g9.xaxis.set_major_locator(loc)
g9.set_yticks(np.arange(0, 60, 10))
g9.tick_params(labelrotation=22.5)
g9.legend(["Acute_Count", "ICU_Count","PSYCH_Count"],
         loc='upper left', frameon=False)
```

Comment: It really doesn't make sense why this would work while the original version didn't.  There is missing too much code of how the subplots were created.

Comment: the table was for some reason I was not able to figure out, capturing the index counts in the Y axis so by removing the index and adding the yticks, the values on the Y axis appeared. (see screenshot of dataframe above)